# Python remove() not removing all items in the list

Tags: python

So i want to delete all 3s from numbers

```
numbers = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
for i in numbers:
    if i == 3:
        numbers.remove(3)
print(numbers)
```

It feels like this should do it but it prints

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

as the result.. It seems like consecutive 3s are the problem but I don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [i for i in numbers if i != 3]
```